# How to surround every X elements with a class using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'd simply like to do something as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
  </div>

   <!-- etc ... -->

</div>
```

Eg, every 3 `.col-md-4's` is wrapped in a `.row`

I've tried:

```
rows.push(<div className="row">);

   for (var count = 0; count < 9; count++) { 

       rows.push( <!-- content --> );

       // Add closing and reopening divs every 3 elements
       if (count % 3 === 0) {
          rows.push(</div><div className="row">);
       }
   }

   rows.push(</div>);
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work.

Furthermore 3 and 9 are just examples here, and I was wondering if there was a generic approach.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should not concatenate elements like a string, but create and compose react elements. You can generate an array of your elements with content first, then reduce it to groups and wrap with your container:

```
render() {
    var content = [
        "content 1", "content 2", "content 3", "content 4", "content 5",
        "content 6", "content 7", "content 8", "content 9", "content 10"
    ];
    var groupSize = 3;
    var rows = content.map(function(content) {
        // map content to html elements
        return <div className="col-md-4">{content}</div>;
    }).reduce(function(r, element, index) {
        // create element groups with size 3, result looks like:
        // [[elem1, elem2, elem3], [elem4, elem5, elem6], ...]
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function(rowContent) {
        // surround every group with 'row'
        return <div className="row">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the line: index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]); is it an assignment or logic operation. What kind of statement is that?

Comment: @antew It's just a shorthand for `if (index % groupSize === 0) { r.push([]) }`. It uses logical operator `&&` to do this conditional logic.

Comment: Here in October 2021, and it doesn't work with Functional React. Is there an answer for me and my hook friends?

Comment: @TalKohavy I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work in functional components in React.

Answer (score 5):

If you're already using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you might be interested in the [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) function:

```
render: function() {
  var rows = [<div className="col-md-4">content</div>, ...]

  return _.chunk(rows, 3).map(function(group) { 
      return <div className="row">{group}</div>
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put just opening/closing tags inside the arrays, collect your columns inside an array and output them all by one, with valid opening and closing tags:

```
rows.push(<div className="row">{columns}</div>);
```